# CodeIgniter does not find guzzlehttp

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working with CodeIgniter 3 and PHP 5.7.
I add in composer `guzzlehttp` with the following command:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0
```

In my `config.php` I put

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

In my library I use

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

But the output is:

> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying with below code:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
```